# Threading in FLTK

Tags: c++, fltk

Firstly, I have reviewed the example `test/threads.cxx`; but it's not exactly the use case I'm looking for as the example threaded function has access to the FLTK functions.

I have a `libssh2` library function (that I wrote, but would love for it not to depend on FLTK), with the following function header:

> int sshSendFile(const char * loclfile, const char * scppath, char *
>   bytesuploaded)

I'd like this to run in a thread, and while in the thread, FLTK spins and reads the value `bytesupload` and updates the label on `Fl_Progress`, which of course sshSendFile is updating as it uploads.

This is what I have so far, actually; once the sshSendFile is completed, my program just ends up exiting in Debug!

```
            Fl::lock();

            char * string_target;

            string_target = (char *)malloc(128);

            void * next_message;

            (Fl_Thread)_beginthread((void(__cdecl *)(void *))sshSendFile("C:/randomfile.txt", "/tmp/testing, string_target), 0,NULL);

            while (Fl::wait() > 0) {
                if ((next_message = Fl::thread_message()) != NULL) {
                    this->progress_bar->label(string_target);
                    this->redraw();
                    Fl::check();
                }
            }

            Fl::unlock();
```

Setting a breakpoint at the `Fl:wait()` is never hit. I'm having a bit of trouble debugging this one and finding the docs not overly clear. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You do all this in very wrong way. 
`_beginthread` expects address of function but you are passing some unrelated value casted to pointer to function. This will lead to access violation error and nothing will work after it.

Comment: C style casts are a good way to introduce bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke `sshSendFile` in main thread and then attempt to start thread with result of this function.

Note that `_beginthread` accepts pointer to function and you must "silence" errors with this ugly cast from `int` to `(void(__cdecl *)(void *))`.

In other words, you must pass function pointer as first argument to `_beginthread` and the easiest way is to just create "thread main" like this:

```
struct Task {
    std::string file;
    ...
}

void sendFiles(void* arg) {
      Task* task = (task*)arg;
      sshSendFiles(task.file.c_str(), ...); 
      delete task;
}
```

and your code for starting thread, should pass this `sendFiles` and a task pointer:

```
task* task = new task();
task->file = "something";
... initialize also buffer
(Fl_Thread)_beginthread(&sendFiles, 0, task);
   // this will call startThread(task) in main thread
```

On the other hand, it would be much easier to use modern threading api from C++11 because what you do now is plain old system level C which is complex, inconvienient and at best deprecated.